# Undefined Method "%" for Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

Code from Controller + Error:

```
def search_conditions
    conditions = []
    if !params[:player_name].nil? && !params[:player_name].empty?
      conditions << ["lower(players.name) LIKE ?", "#{params[:player_name].downcase}%"]
    end
    conditions
end

def index
    @games = Game.joins([:player_one, :player_two]).where(search_conditions)
end

undefined method `%' for ["lower(players.name) LIKE ?", "test%"]:Array
Stack Trace:
activerecord (3.2.6) lib/active_record/sanitization.rb:121:in `sanitize_sql_array'
activerecord (3.2.6) lib/active_record/sanitization.rb:28:in `sanitize_sql_for_conditions'
activerecord (3.2.6) lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:324:in `build_where'
activerecord (3.2.6) lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:136:in `where'
app/controllers/game_controller.rb:5:in `index'
```

Looking at the stack trace, I search through the active record source and was able to find the line causing the issue in the sanitize_sql_array method:

```
statement % values.collect { |value| connection.quote_string(value.to_s) }
```

Now, I don't know enough about ruby to know exactly what that line does. I thought it initially had to do with the percent sign in the string, but removing it results in the same error still. I've also even tried constructing the string completely with creating a multidimensional array, but I still get the same error.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but I'd suggest changing `if !params[:player_name].nil? && !params[:player_name].empty?` to `if params[:player_name].present?` Basically, `object.blank?` returns `true` if it's nil or empty. `object.present?` returns `true` if `object.blank?` returns `false`. These are Rails methods, but it looks like you're working with Rails, so I thought I'd throw that out there.

Comment: @MichaelStalker Thanks! I didn't know about the .present? method. I'll definitely use that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're passing an array of arrays to `where`, rather than just an array. This means `statement` gets set as an array, but it expects a string (`%` on a string does string formatting, e.g: `"hello %s" % "world" => "hello world"`).

```
conditions = []
conditions << ["lower(players.name) LIKE ?", "#{params[:player_name].downcase}%"]

  => [ ["lower(players.name) LIKE ?", "..."] ]
```

Change:

```
conditions << ["lower(players.name) LIKE ?", "#{params[:player_name].downcase}%"]
```

to:

```
conditions.push "lower(players.name) LIKE ?", "#{params[:player_name].downcase}%"
```

Comment: That worked! I thought I saw that done on another website somewhere but I guess they were wrong. I thought that's what the % sign did, but the way the statement was had me a little confused. Thanks again!